# Linear algebra package over integers

Tags: linear-algebra, math-software

Is there a fast and friendly tool for matrix-computations over $\Bbb Z$? In particular, I would like to find generators of the solution of a homogenous system of linear equations. This can be done using the computation of Smith Normal Form.

I checked online and most references lead to the [LinBox](http://www.linalg.org/download.html) project but it seems unspported and links to documentation are dead..

Comment: If you can use Mathematica, try this: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7081/. For Maple, see http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=LinearAlgebra/SmithForm. For GAP, see http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap25_mj.html.